# Redirection from REST service to web page

Tags: rest, http, redirect

Is it ok to redirect from REST service (with HTTP 307 code) to web page on another server. F.e. I want to redirect user to wikipedia.com page from rest service. Does it violate http or rest protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you consume your REST service (eg. AJAX, Mobile / Desktop Client, Server-side Application). Your question does not *violate* the RFC2616 but I am not really sure how this will be useful unless your service is accessed via Browsers directly.

However, I would not recommend to redirect via 307 rather than 303 (307 means the user should repeat the same request to the new URL specified in the Location header field (so if the last request was POST, the request to the new URL will also be POST) and not all clients might support that status. See [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.8) definition of 307.

Can you provide more information of how you are planning to use this?

*Edit:* Changed to `303 See other` as this is more appropriate here.

Comment: I'm planning to handling users request to rest service, where i'll make some operation (f.e. logging to db) and redirect to web page with appropriate content. It may be weird why I want to use rest service to achieve this goal, but i want to combine restAPI (which i need for my application) and something like tracking feature

Comment: Ok, yes it is no problem to redirect to another domain. I was just curious if you are returning html content (for browsers) all the time.

Long story short: Just use `HTTP 303 See other` and the Location header field with the new URL to redirect.